# PyODBC fetch result from a simple SELECT clause

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I have a SQL script like follows:

> DECLARE @AGE INT = ?
>
> ,  @NAME VARCHAR(20) = ?
>
> INSERT INTO [dbo].[new_table] (AGE, NAME)
>
> SELECT @AGE, @NAME
>
> SELECT ID = CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT)

In the table, there is an `IDENTITY column ID` which is defined as `INT`. Thus the values of the `ID` column is increasing as new rows are inserted. `And my goal is to take out the` ID `that just inserted.`

The above code works fine in SQL.

Then I tried to run it in python, using following code:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("driver={SQL Server}; server= MyServer; database= MyDatabase"; trusted_connection=true") 

cursor = conn .cursor()

SQL_command = """
                 DECLARE @AGE INT = ? 
                     ,  @NAME VARCHAR(20) = ?
 
                 INSERT INTO [dbo].[new_table] (AGE, NAME) 
                 SELECT @AGE, @NAME
 
                 SELECT ID = CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT)
              """

cursor.execute(SQL_command, 23, 'TOM')

result = cursor.fetchall()
```

However, I've got following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\wwang\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\ComparablesBuilder\test.py", line 119, in
>
> ```
> result = cursor.fetchall()
> ```
>
> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.

So, may I know why the same code cannot work in python? Is my usage of pyodbc is incorrect?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the multiple statements in your Sql Batch are being interpreted as separate result sets to the Python driver - the first row-count returning statement is the `INSERT` statement, which could be the culprit.

Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON;` before your statements, to suppress row counts from non-queries:

```
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 DECLARE @AGE INT = ? 
      ,  @NAME VARCHAR(20) = ?

 ... 
 SELECT ID = CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT);
```

**Edit**

IIRC, some drivers are also dependent on Sql Server's `ROW COUNT` to parse result sets correctly. So if the above fails, you might also try:

```
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE ...;
  INSERT ...;

  SET NOCOUNT OFF; -- i.e. Turn back on again so the 1 row count can be returned.
  SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT) AS ID;
```